# How to get your firebase email from google-service.json

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-account

I know that is a hard request but I have a way to know the email account matched by my old project because they stopped my database and I want to fixe it.

So there is a solution to get at least the email from the google-service json or AuthSecret and BasePath or connect to the project with it???

Plz help me guys....

or there is a way to activate my data base without login to firebase dashboard ??

when I type the dtabase url I got:

> {   "error" : "The Firebase database 'olaenergie-40682' has been
> deactivated." }